# My homemade plugin is trying to update to someone else's plugin

Tags: plugins, updates, cache

Wordpress is telling me that my self-built plugin has an update available, and this link leads me to someone else's repo.

After I first saw this message, I read a lot of questions on here asking similar questions, and have tried several things to try to get rid of this update available message, including:

- Ensuring both the folder name and filename are unique, even trying a random number at the end
- Changing the name of the plugin
- Changing the post type slug

None of these made a difference. The only think that seems to have worked so far is a really high version number (a horrible solution).

I thought perhaps Wordpress could be caching something somewhere? I don't have any caching plugins installed by the way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the plugin header (the PHP comment with Plugin Name, Plugin URI, etc.) in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out that wordpress does cache available updates in the wp_options table in an option named `_site_transient_update_plugins`.

By clearing this value I was able to get Wordpress to notice my changes. I used the following query:

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='' WHERE option_name='_site_transient_update_plugins';`

Answer (score 3):

Do **not** rely on changing plugin details to work around this issue. The code that decides a match in official repository is a black box — they don’t disclose how it works and what it considers, except in very general terms. Even if it ignores your plugin *today*, who knows if it will do the same tomorrow?

Any WP site that runs non–repo extensions *needs* to properly and definitively block possibility of their breakage from invalid updates.

Personally I got tired of the issue and made my own wheel for it as [Update Blocker](https://github.com/Rarst/update-blocker) plugin. I am sure there are more alternatives around.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although your plugin seems like the "nuclear" approach, as it seems to disable all updates, even where needed which is not suitable for me. In my case, the issue was more the fact that my changes to fix the problem were not seeming to take effect. I think I've found the answer though and will post separately. Thanks.

Comment: My plugin is completely configurable for whatever you need. :) If not — GitHub issues welcomed. :)